# Stata - run code if variable name contained in local

Tags: if-statement, stata, locals

I would like to have an `if` condition in Stata which runs the code in braces for a certain variable only if that variable's name is contained in a `local`. E.g.

```
if (`variable` element of `variablenames_local`) {
    gen variable2 = variable + 2
}
```

How can this be done in Stata?

Answer (score 2):

You can use extended macro functions for that, which are documented in `help extended_fcn`. In this case `help macrolist` is very useful. (I never remember the names of those help-files, instead I usually type `help macro` or `help local` and follow the links in that help-file.)

```
sysuse auto, clear

local vars "price mpg foreign"

foreach var of varlist _all {
    if `: list var in vars' {
        di "do something smart with `var'"
    }
}

// alternatively:
foreach var of varlist `vars' {
    di "do something smart with `var'"
}
```

Comment: This is just to underline that the second is immensely better style. There may be some context you are not telling about, but selecting the variables you want just once beats selecting them one by one.

Comment: In the example above @NickCox is absolutely right. I have occationally used the first trick when parsing complex syntax elements.